# Wordpress Create an API with Custom Content Types

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website built with WordPress, and it uses Custom Content Types plugin to create a form with custom fields suitable to the websites need.

Today I am trying to create a mobile app that will fetch the data from this website. therefore I figured I should install an API plugin. but apparently, non of the support custom content types, and allows only requests with posts / pages / taxonomies data.

Any ideas on how I can create an API with custom content types?

Comment: You could write AJAX functions in your theme that spit out the content.

Comment: you mean an AJAX function that runs over all the HTML and splits the content from the HTML? this is a big performance NO NO

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. Build your own API, as in you send a POST request to yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php passing an action and the postID, which will return the post content.

Comment: well... building my own API is very complex task. I prefer focusing on my development instead of creating everything from scratch. that is the main feature of WordPress, it gives you a lot of functions out of the box, sometimes you should just find them.

Comment: Lol if you seem to know the answer then why did you ask the question? There are also plugins that expose your content as an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue I used WP Json Rest API plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Thanks.